# @PostConstruct method not called when deploying onto Glassfish

Tags: maven-2, ejb, glassfish-3, war, liquibase

I am planning to use LiquiBase to manage a database, I want it to run every time when I deploy the web application to Glassfish 3.1. In order to do this I wrote the following class:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class LiquibaseWrapper {

    @Resource(name = "jdbc/mydatabase")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void doLiquibaseUpdate() {
        ResourceAccessor fileOpener = new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor();
        DatabaseFactory databaseFactory = DatabaseFactory.getInstance();
        Database database = null;
        try {
            database = databaseFactory
                    .findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new Jdbc Connection(
                            dataSource.getConnection()));
            Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("ChangeLog.xml",
                    fileOpener, database);
            liquibase.update("");
        } catch (DatabaseException e) {
            // TODO: handle error
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO: handle error
        } catch (LiquibaseException e) {
            // TODO: handle error
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I deploy the application onto the server via Eclipse, doLiquiBaseUpdate() is not executed. When I build a WAR file out of it, and manually deploy it, the method is executed.

I am somewhat confused why doLiquiBaseUpdate() does not run when deploying through eclipse.

Other potentially useful information:
   - WARs are being build with Maven 2
   - Using JSF 2.1 
   - Database is MySQL
   - Using LiquiBase 2.0.3
   - Eclipse Indigo with Glassfish server tool 1.7.3